# How do I compile my C# library that uses external dependencies without them included in the library?

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, libraries

I am making my own `C#` library that uses `OpenTK` methods. Naturally, I would have to include the `OpenTK` dependencies in order to use them in my project. When I compile my library and include it in my new project as a new external dependency, the `OpenTK` dependencies are being included as well. My goal is to not include the `OpenTK` dependencies within my self-made library that uses them, but rather have the user download required dependencies before using mine. Is that possible? Is that even a thing that matters? I am not familiar with libraries in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuget packages could help you here. Add OpenTK nuget package reference and share your library as nuget package. In this case your nuget package won't have the assemblies of OpenTK instead will have a reference to OpenTK nuget package. When some one adds your package as a nuget package reference the nuget package installer looks for all other nuget package dependences and will install automatically.

One caveat is that if you have any non-nuget package references in your package then those assemblies will be part of your nuget package itself.

Comment: Thanks! I was worried about grabbing a whole dependency, but turns out, NuGet is designed to make life easier.